# Estimating a complex path integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis

Consider the following integral
$$\int_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \frac{z^2 + z + 1}{z^4 - 5z^2 -1}\, \mathrm d z.$$
I want to show that this integral converges to $0$ as $r \to \infty$.
I would estimate as follows:
\begin{align*}
\bigg\lvert\int_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \frac{z^2 + z + 1}{z^4 - 5z^2 -1}\, \mathrm d z \bigg\rvert &\leq 2 \pi r \cdot \sup_{\lvert z \rvert = r} \bigg \lvert \frac{z^2 + z + 1}{z^4 - 5z^2 -1} \bigg\rvert \\
&= 2 \pi r \cdot \sup_{\phi \in [0, 2 \pi]} \bigg \lvert \frac{r^2 \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm i \phi} + r \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm i \phi} + 1}{r^4 \mathrm{e}^{4 \mathrm i \phi} - 5r^2 \mathrm{e}^{2 \mathrm i \phi} -1} \bigg\rvert
\end{align*}
But I do not get how to estimate this supremum. It is heuristically clear that the term should behave like $\frac{1}{r^2}$ as $r \to \infty$. But that is not a proof. Looking forward to some hints.

Comment: Before substituting $z=re^{2i\phi}$, try using the triangle inequality (and the reverse triangle inequality) to find a "nicer" term to compute its supremum, while still keeping the term behaving asymptotically as $\frac{1}{r^2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $R\gg0$, then$$|z|>R\implies\left\lvert\frac{z^2+z+1}{z^4-5z^2-1}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac2{|z|^2},$$and therefore$$r\geqslant R\implies\left\lvert\int_{|z|=r}\frac{z^2+z+1}{z^4-5z^2-1}\,\mathrm dz\right\rvert\leqslant\frac{2\times2\pi r}{r^2}=\frac{4\pi}r.$$Now, use the fact that$$\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{4\pi}r=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

if we have $z^4-5z^2-1=0$ and let $Z=z^2$ we get: $Z^2-5Z-1=0$ which gives:
$$Z_{1,2}=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{29}}{2}$$
so $z$ will have 2 real roots and 2 imaginary roots, so it might be worth splitting up the quartic into 2 quadratics?